# `UITableView.appearance().sectionFooterHeight = 0` no longer working iOS16?

Tags: swiftui, ios16

Since updating to iOS, I've noticed `UITableView.appearance().sectionFooterHeight = 0` no longer works in my app (or in Xcode 14), screenshots attatched for reference, and here's how I was using it:

```swift
init() {
    UITableView.appearance().sectionFooterHeight = 0
}
```

##### Before iOS16

[image]

##### After iOS16

[image]

If something has changed, what's the updated version of this?

Comment: `List` is no longer backed by `UITableView`. Have you tried setting the height explicitly?

Comment: How do i set the space between section height explicitly?